# How to solve "No module named 'pyasn1_modules.rfc2251'" in python-ldap

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap

I am trying to run python-ldap in linux.
This is working fine in windows (wierd).
ldap import is itself not working.

```
import ldap
l = ldap.initialize('ldap://XXX.XXXX:XXXX')
username = "XXXXX"
password = "XXXX"
baseDN = "DC=XXX,DC=XX"
```

But i am facing error:

```
from pyasn1_modules.rfc2251 import LDAPDN
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyasn1_modules.rfc2251'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this means the right PIP module is not installed. 
In windows you would have to go to CMD and type: python -m pip install pyasn1
In linux you may be able to do the same in Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the package:

```
sudo pip install pyasn1_modules
```